# OWLCarousel CSS3 problem in -webkit style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I dragged the code of owl carousel from its site css and Js included but there's eror on every -webkit, -mos, -ms . I looked further but they asked to add JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation : false,
        rtl:true,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        autoplay:true,
        singleItem:true
    }); 
})
```

but didn't work!

```css
/**
 * Owl Carousel v2.3.4
 * Copyright 2013-2018 David Deutsch
 * Licensed under: SEE LICENSE IN https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/master/LICENSE
 */
.owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative
}

.owl-carousel {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item,
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled {
    display: none
}

.no-js .owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dot,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    background: 0 0;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font: inherit
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block
}

.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 0
}

.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
    visibility: hidden
}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}

.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grab
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
    direction: rtl
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
    float: right
}

.owl-carousel .animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
    z-index: 0
}

.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
    z-index: 1
}

.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
    animation-name: fadeOut
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}

.owl-height {
    transition: height .5s ease-in-out
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]),
.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""] {
    max-height: 0
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy {
    transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    background: url(owl.video.play.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .1s ease
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3, 1.3)
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon,
.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn {
    display: none
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: opacity .4s ease
}

.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

by the way this is just a dummy project

these code are of only carousel i have more of different section!

Answer (score 0):

Following is a demo from their website,

Please read their installation steps properly [Installation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html)

Refer to the order of CSS and js included. Note that you have to include the owl-theme css also

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  height: 10rem;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" integrity="sha512-UTNP5BXLIptsaj5WdKFrkFov94lDx+eBvbKyoe1YAfjeRPC+gT5kyZ10kOHCfNZqEui1sxmqvodNUx3KbuYI/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" integrity="sha512-OTcub78R3msOCtY3Tc6FzeDJ8N9qvQn1Ph49ou13xgA9VsH9+LRxoFU6EqLhW4+PKRfU+/HReXmSZXHEkpYoOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```